# How to Multiply Product unit with feature value in cart summary Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, prestashop

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JIRL.png)
(Prestashop) I added a image of Cart summary. So I added product features in cart summary and one of them is "Bag" which is weight in Kg. "Total KG" section shows total weight means "product quantity x Bag weight". 
I used this code and it's working when we click add to cart.

```
<td>
{assign var="features"     value=Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic(Context::getContext()->language->id,   $product.id_product)} 
{foreach $features as $feature}
{if $feature.id_feature == 9}
<div>{$feature.value*$product.cart_quantity|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} Kg</div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</td>
```

But when we increase quantity directly through cart summary page through + and - buttons then it's not working. I know it is possible but using ajax only.

Comment: In your theme folder under `js` folder is a file `cart-summary.js` which handles ajax updates in cart summary page. At line 786 (at least in default theme's js file) is a function `updateCartSummary()` which updates page data after ajax call. You can add your modifications there. That's one of many possible ways to do it to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When product quantity is modified on the Cart page then an Ajax request is sent to CartController.php (front) and which finally calls updateQty() function in Cart.php class file.

So you need to add the code that you are using to updateQty() function as well.